# Can you request review for User Interface code?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have been working on a software since a while in Java, and started the designing phase of it. I use JavaFX for the GUI, and use FXML for defining Scenes. I want to get the code reviewed which is related to how I handle the user interface. Like, how I render different pages, etc. Would that be considered on-topic on CodeReview?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that would be considered on-topic, often we review even [css](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css) designs here.

Just make sure you include some working code and you should be fine!

Comment: Yeah, that code contains CSS definitely, to style up the default elements.